# boost::filesystem::path changes base variable with operator /=

Tags: c++, boost

I'm having a directory where multiple files are stored in.

e.g. C:\test\
with contents: test.txt, info.txt, dir2/

When using `boost::system::filepath` there is the possibility to use the systems path seperators with the operators `/=` and `+=`.
Both functions change the base variable - using a temporary variable seems quite some overhead and I'm wondering if I forgot some kind of operator or function that covers my need.

For example

```
boost::filesystem::path pathTmp = boost::filesystem::current_path(); // imagine this returns C:\test
function1( pathTmp /= "test.txt" ); // this would call the function1 with "C:\test\test.txt" but also modify pathTmp
```

After this function1 call I'd need to remove the filename to get back to the directory and call the function again with the next filename. Or I make a temporary copy of `pathTmp` and reassign this temporary copy to `pathTmp` and go from there:

```
boost::filesystem::path pathCopy = pathTmp = boost::filesystem::current_path(); // imagine this returns C:\test
function1( pathTmp /= "test.txt" ); // this would call the function1 with "C:\test\test.txt" but also modify pathTmp
pathTmp = pathCopy;
function1( pathTmp /= "info.txt" );
```

I was wondering if I forgot some kind of function to add a filename to a path with the right separator without the need of temporary copies or expensive calls to remove the filename again.

Comment: Just use `operator/` ?

Comment: Perfect answer to my question. Since you didn't answer I'll update this question as solved by quoting your answer! +1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @cpplearner answerd in a comment to my question, I'm quoting him and marking this as answer

> Just use operator/ ? – cpplearner

Answer (score 2):

Operator `/=` changes the left-hand side in all programming languages I know of (including, but not limited to, C, C##, C++).

In general:

```
 x += y; // is equivalent to x = x + y; 
 x -= y; // is equivalent to x = x - y; 
 x /= y; // is equivalent to x = x / y; 
 x *= y; // is equivalent to x = x * y; 
 x &= y; // is equivalent to x = x & y; 
 x |= y; // is equivalent to x = x | y; 
 x ^= y; // is equivalent to x = x ^ y; 
 x %= y; // is equivalent to x = x % y;
```

Comment: Yeah that's the case, except when the operators are overridden as with boost::filesystem::path, then they have a different functionality

Comment: Apparently not in this case. Actually  that's the driving design principle for types with overloaded operators (Principle Of Least Surprise)

Comment: `path a,b;` Equivalent : `a/=b` and `a = a/b`